# Canon EF 70-200mm 1:2.8 L IS III USM lens hood diameter?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-hood

The Canon EF 70-200mm 1:2.8 L IS III USM is specified to have a max outside diameter of 89mm, but I assume that is without the lens hood (ET-87) attached.

I can't seem to find the outside diameter of the lens hood. I'd like to check if my camera bag would fit the lens with the hood attached in reverse for storage.

Comment: Personally, I’d buy a bag to fit my lenses instead of lenses to fit my bag. That bag must be some kind of awesome ;-)

Comment: fair enough. I'm planning on making my own bag. I figure I might as well design it around my dream lens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ET-87 hood that came with my EF 70-200mm f/2.8L IS II lens in 2010 measures 4 3/8 inches (112 mm) at the widest point.

Answer (score 1):

Using the pictures in an [Amazon entry for a rip-off](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G3Q9M5C), if the filter diameter is 77mm then the external diameter of the hood is around 115mm.